# Multiply 2dim numpy array with vector to get 3dim array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array which is 2d and an 1d array

```
In [127]: A = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]])

In [128]: B = np.array([10, 100])
```

What I would like to achieve is to get a 3d array `C`, where `C[:, :, 0] = A*B[0]` and `C[:, :, 1] = A*B[1]`. I was able to do it via `np.einsum` but looks like an overkill.

```
In [129]: np.einsum('ij, k -> ijk', A, B)[:, :, 0]
Out[129]: 
array([[10, 20],
       [30, 40]])

In [130]: np.einsum('ij, k -> ijk', A, B)[:, :, 1]
Out[130]: 
array([[100, 200],
       [300, 400]])
```

Is there a simpler version?

Comment: `B[:,None,None]*A`?

Comment: Use broadcasting with a new (3rd) dimension. Oh, just like what @Divakar stated

Comment: What about : `C = np.einsum('ij, k -> ijk', A, B)` as you were already using? I suspect `A[...,None]*B` would be faster to get the equivalent of `C[:, :, 0] = A*B[0] and C[:, :, 1] = A*B[1]`.

Comment: @Divakar cool, many thx. happy to accept it as an answer if you post it. And I think it should be `B[None, None, :] *A` to be equivalent to my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `B` for scaling along the first axis, we can simply use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) like so -

```
B[:,None,None]*A # with einsum : np.einsum('ij, k -> kij', A, B)
```

To get the equivalent of `C[:, :, 0] = A*B[0] and C[:, :, 1] = A*B[1]`, we need to extend `A` instead -

```
A[...,None]*B # with einsum : np.einsum('ij, k -> ijk', A, B)
```

With no sum-reductions happening in here, `broadcasting` based ones would be faster than `einsum` ones.